# Ember.js - Creating/Editing and Deleting model using RESTAdapter

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Ember has `find()` method to issue `GET` towards the server. You can do it with `id` or without.
I am looking at the official guide and I'm missing something important:

[image]

I cannot find the methods which suppose to make my life easier, what are the methods which invoke PUT/POST and DELETE?

I'm using `FixtureAdapter`, I want to make sure the methods for add/delete and edit, that I'm writing now, will be functional with the `RESTAdapter` when my server side will be completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fixture adapter doesn't make any calls back to the server, so it's harder to see, but if you look in the restadapter code you can see the calls that do the put/post/delete.

updateRecord: This exsits on the adapter itself, really you should call save on a model and allow ember data to choose the updateRecord on its own. **model.save()**

createRecord: this should be called from the Class **App.KewlKidz.createRecord({id:3, name:"me"});**

deleteRecord: call this bad boy on the model.  **model.deleteRecord()**

[Rest Adapter](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js)

[Ember Data Model](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/model/model.js)

Comment: I don't quite understand the last sentence, it seems both put and delete use the same model. Is it a mistake?

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about... ;)  Just messing, copy paste error on my part.